# How to put a condition in a specific column in jtable

Tags: java, conditional-statements, jtable

How to put a if else condition in a specific column in jtable. the condition is that.. if you put a number that is less than or equal to 3 (<=3) there will be a pop up a msg that the value is too low.

I don't know where to put the code im still new in using a jtable

Comment: probably add a `CellEditorListener` to the corresponding cell editor (`getDefaultCellEditor()`) or even use a customized cell editor - also have a look at Oracle's Tutorial section [Using an Editor to Validate User-Entered Text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#validtext) (including the other sections)

Comment: Create a custom cell editor. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64190732/131872 for an example.