# How to update one cell in JTable if it's not getting updated when cell is left empty

Tags: java, swing, jtable, awt

I am working on a modifiable table, each cell that is modified gets directly updated in the database. What I want is that whenever you try to edit a cell, if it's left in blank, it doesn't get updated (which works) and repaint the cell with previous value (this is the problem). The data does not get updated, it throws an error message, but the cell is still blank and doesn't get the value back until is refreshed.

I've thought of having a mouseclick listener and a global variable where the previous value is stored when clicked, but this is giving me problems with other cells as I'm using a JDateChooser and it kinda breaks with this option while restoring the date. I've tried using `model.fireTableCellUpdated(x,y)`, but I'm getting a StackOverflow error, so I don't have any more ideas left.

This is the code, it's getting fired by a TableModelListener:

(The commented part inside the if is what I tried with the global variable)

```
private static void updateMember(TableModelEvent e, Database db, JTable tabla) {
        if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE) {
            AbstractTableModel modelo = ((AbstractTableModel) e.getSource());
            int row= e.getFirstRow();
            int column = e.getColumn();

            String dato=String.valueOf(modelo.getValueAt(row,column));  
            String id_user = String.valueOf(modelo.getValueAt(row, 0));
            System.out.println(dato + "?");
            
            String update = columns[column];
            
            if (dato.isEmpty()) {
                modelo.fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);
//              modelo.setValueAt(selectedValue, row, column);
//              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No puedes dejar el campo vacío", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);                  
         
            } else {
                db.executeUpdate(update, dato, id_user);
                System.out.println(update);             
            }
        }   
    }
```

The listener used for the mouse clicked idea:

```
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                selectedValue = String.valueOf(tabla.getModel().getValueAt(tabla.getSelectedRow(), tabla.getSelectedColumn()));
                System.out.println("Fila: " + tabla.getSelectedRow() + "Columna: " + tabla.getSelectedColumn());                    
                
            }
        });
```

Comment: I think you can use the [Table Cell Listener](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/). It tracks the original value and only generates an event when the data is changed.

Comment: But it would also take as data changed when you delete the content of a cell, wouldn't it?

Comment: Not understanding the problem. You check the value. If it is empty/blank (whatever your condition) you restore the original value. You could also add a custom editor to the column to not save the data if it is empty. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64190732/131872 for an example that won't allow the editor to save the data if it is not valid.